# Ajax " async = false " deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to get user's location and store that in a variable.
My code works fine but it is showing this warning:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

This is my code:

```
var myJson = $.ajax({
    url: requestUrl,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json'
}).responseJSON;

var country = myJson.country;

console.log(country);
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok and? The warning is there for a reason

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. I've closed this as my best guess for a duplicate as to what you were trying to get at … otherwise it would have probably been closed as "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: I obviously want to get rid of the warning somehow, any ideas?

Comment: You can either ignore it or use the function asynchronously.

Comment: @h_h10a — Don't make the request synchronous